# Is it okay to add sensitive config to heroku.yml files and committing to Heroku's GIT repo?

Tags: heroku

In the Heroku documentation, Heroku gives you the option to add enviornment variables in the setup.config section in heroku.yml. Then, you are supposed to commit these files to heroku's remote git repo. Is this okay? Or is there a better place to do this?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#heroku-yml-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not ok. You should never add sensitive values to your GIT repository.
Unfortunately, Heroku doesn't give any way to send secure/encrypted values when using heroku.yml files.
So if this is something you need to do, you will not be able to use that feature.

Comment: Thank you! I will be using heroku config:set VARIABLE_KEY=VARIABLE_VALUE instead.